# Passing a constant reference into a function

Tags: c++

I am trying to pass a constant integer into a function using pass by reference.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int test(int& num);
// changes a constant variable

int main() {
  int loopSize = 7;
  const int SIZE = loopSize;
  cout<<SIZE<<endl;
  test(loopSize);
  cout<<SIZE;
  return 0;
}

int test(int& num){
  num -= 2;
}
```

However, the output is never updated.

Comment: `test(SIZE)` not `test(loopSize)`

Comment: But you shouldn't try to modify a constant anyway.

Comment: I am very new to C++, but what is going on with this line? `int test(int& num); // changes a constant variable`

Comment: It's not hard to get around `const` if you try, but it's your own fault when things break.

Comment: You can't change the value of constant this way

Comment: @tjons, It declares a function `test` that takes a reference to `int` and returns `int`.

Comment: @chris thanks for answering. But if that is so, why is the function body later defined? Why not do it all at once?

Comment: @tjons, Various reasons, but this isn't the place. I recommend picking up a [book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Your question is equivalent to this: `a = 2; b = 4;` `b -= 2;` Can anyone tell me why `a`'s value doesn't change?

Comment: @tjons: In this particular example, there is no reason. `test` could have been defined first. I would have done. In such examples it tends to be because people are taught this way, mostly from C heritage. In practice, function definitions tend to be hived off into other files so that could be why. But you're right to question it in this particular example.

Answer (score 6):

`SIZE` and `loopSize` are two different objects. Even though `SIZE` started its life with `loopSize`'s value at the time, changing one won't change the other. `SIZE` is not a reference.

Indeed, since `SIZE` is a constant you could never reasonably expect it to change *anyway*!

Is it possible that you intended to write the following?

```
const int& SIZE = loopSize;
//       ^
```

Answer (score 0):

You are changing loopSize and printing SIZE, so obviously the value won't change. Also, SIZE is a const, it won't change anyway.